# Find string in list within list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects with lists:

```
ls = [
    {'id': 1, 'content': ['lorem', 'ipsum']},
    {'id': 1, 'content': ['dolor', 'sit', 'amet']},
]
```

i want to get the index of the object with e.g. `'lorem'`

So far i tried:

```
'lorem' in [x['content'] for x in ls]
```

This does not return true nor does it return an index.

Comment: what would be the index for `'ipsum'`? `0`? `1`? `(0, 1)`?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? After spending over a decade in other languages, I've finally started learning python and really like this question. I wish downvotes came with reasons.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms The reason for my downvote is explained by MSeifert's question. As it is, this question cannot be answered because an essential part is missing.

Comment: @Rawing A dictionary looks more like an "object" to me than a list, so it seemed obvious to me that that was what the OP was referring to. But \@5h3z4n, please edit if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Rawing But now that you mention it, I can see other possible interpretations. You are quite right the original question was not as clear as I originally thought.

Comment: Please explain your question more. I'll restate MSeifert's comment: If you are searching for `'ipsum'`, are you only looking for the index referring to the dictionary item `{'id': 1, 'content': ['lorem', 'ipsum']}` (i.e. `0`), the index of `'ipsum'` inside its list (i.e. `1`), or a combined index referring to both (i.e. `(0, 1)`). _I reverted my previous edit when I realized that there were multiple ways to understand the original question_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm sets a keyword to a string and then searches through the list of dictionaries to see if the keyword exists the value for the key 'content'. If it does exist, the index is returned. If it does not, "not found" is returned.

```
keyword = "dolor"

ls = [
{'id': 1, 'content': ['lorem', 'ipsum']},
{'id': 1, 'content': ['dolor', 'sit', 'amet']},
]

indices = [i['content'].index(keyword) if keyword in i['content'] else "not found" for i in ls]
```

Edit:

Another way to find the index without a "not found" statement can be done below:

```
 [i['content'].index(keyword) for i in ls if keyword in i['content']]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls.index([x for x in ls if 'lorem' in x['content']][0])`
This oneline style has the same result as follows:

```
t = []
for x in ls:
    if 'lorem' in x['content']:
        t.append(x)
ls.index(t[0])
```

On my machine, the output is:

```
>>> ls.index([x for x in ls if 'lorem' in x['content']][0])
0
>>> ls.index([x for x in ls if 'ipsum' in x['content']][0])
0
>>> ls.index([x for x in ls if 'dolor' in x['content']][0])
1
>>> ls.index([x for x in ls if 'sit' in x['content']][0])
1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
 >>> tgt='ipsum'
 >>> [(x, di['content'].index(tgt)) for x, di in enumerate(ls) if tgt in di['content']]
 [(0, 1)]
 >>> tgt='amet'
 >>> [(x, di['content'].index(tgt)) for x, di in enumerate(ls) if tgt in di['content']]
 [(1, 2)]
```

This assumes that a dict with `['content']` is inside the list of dicts.